# bootstrap breadcrumb example with default javascript file

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

Take a look this [link](http://jeluard.github.io/bootstrap-breadcrumb/).

I am trying to implement this. My problem is what are the "options" variable in script?
Imagine this html code for my breadcrumb:

```
<div>
   <ul class="breadcrumb" id="breadcrumb">
       <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

After this, I have something like this for my lateral menu:

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="b-link" href="@Url.Content("~/Produts")">Produts</a></li>
   <li><a class="b-link" href="@Url.Content("~/Clients")">Clients</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then, when I click in Produts, I want that breadcrumb changes dynamically using bootstrap-breadcrumb.js.

I think that the javascript should look like the code below, but, **what are the options**?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var breadcrumb = $('#breadcrumb').breadcrumb(options);
      $('a.b-link').click(function () {
         breadcrumb.push($(this).text());
         //breadcrumb.pop();
      });
});
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much.

P.S. My project is in MVC 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can pass divider to it, since the options are just passed down to settings and the only thing used in settings is divider. So you can have '|', '*' or anything else passed down and used as dividers. Instead of the default '/'

```
$.fn.breadcrumb.defaults = {
    divider: '/', 
    keyboard: false
}
```

Seems to match with the documentation as well: 
http://jeluard.github.io/bootstrap-breadcrumb/index.html

> Options
>
> Name  type    default description divider string  /   String used as divider.